# Javascript SetInterval() scope problem

Tags: javascript, scope, setinterval

I wrote a class in javascript that looks like this:

```
function main()
{
    this.var1 =0;
    this.clock = function()
    {
        var t = this;
        var n =1;
        window.setInterval(document.write(this.n++),1000);
    }
}
```

But after calling setInterval() 'this' refers to window.  So i cannot access the variable inside the class. How can I solve this scope problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function main()
{
    this.var1 =0;
    this.clock = function()
    {
        var t = this;
        var n = 1;
        window.setInterval(function(){ document.write(n++); },1000);
    }
}
```

Notice that your code is wrapped in `function`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your `setInterval` isn't doing what you think.  You're doing a setInterval on the ***result*** of `document.write(this.n++)`.  The write happens immediately and will only ever fire once.

Code should be:

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.write(n++);
}, 1000);
```

setInterval takes a function to execute every `n` ms.  The scope of the function has access to your `n` variable, so you don't need a `this`

Comment: But I am not getting desired output when I am passing method of the same class,as like you suggested

Comment: I don't follow.  Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1):

```
function main()
{
    this.var1 =0;
    this.clock = function()
    {
        var t = this;
        var n = 1;
        window.setInterval(function(){ document.write( t.n++); },1000);
    }
}
```

You already declared `t`, use it! All guys are correct, use the function statement, but to mantain `n` in the scope use `t`.

Answer (score 0):

document.write.... now that's old school. Try `document.write(main.n++)` instead?

Comment: Which object of main will be reffered if i do so?